# How to unlink axes for Panel objects in Holoviews

Tags: python, holoviews

I am trying to create two graphs that depend on the same slider values. Unfortunately, when I try to move the graph of one, I move the axes of the other. In addition, the xlims are linked when they are not supposed to, even when they are set explicitly. This is causing my plotted curves to be off the graph. I attached pictures for reference. How do I make it so the graphs are independent?

[image: Two graphs that both use the same "Hour" and "Statistic" widget slider. Notice that the axes are linked, when they are not supposed to.]

[image: Normal ECDF graph when not linked in the panel]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I found out the answer. There's a keyword "shared_axes" that you can set to be False. Put this in `.opts(shared_axes=False)` for both plots.

Comment: Yes, this solution will work and is sometimes needed. However, I think there's a deeper issue, namely not having not given your plot dimensions accurate names when you created the plot. HoloViews only links dimensions with the same name and units, which is nearly always the right thing to do if things are named properly, but if everything is just called `x` and `y` HoloViews won't realize those are meant to be different dimensions. Here, the second plot's y axis seems like it should be declared "density" in the vdims argument when you create each object, and similarly declare x in the kdims.